# How do you dynamically create useState variables in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, variable-names

I am working on a React application that is essentially a virtual library of books. Users are able to view shelves that show what they are currently reading, have already read, want to read, etc.

As part of this application, I allow users to add a custom "shelf" that would display a new category of books (.e.g. "December Book Club", or "Audiobooks"). Each shelf that is rendered has its own state in order to keep track of which books belong to that collection.

How do I dynamically create useState varibles in React. For example, if the user input the name "Audiobooks", I want to create a new set of useState variables for that shelf :

`const [audiobooks, setAudiobooks] = useState([]);`

I'm having trouble with dynamically creating those variable names so that I can use them elsewhere in my code.

I have a function that accepts a camelcase name, and a startingValue.

```
const newStateVariable = (name, startingValue) =>{
  // prepend "set" to the name with first letter capitalized
  const setter = "set" + _.capitalize(name);

  const [ eval(name), eval(setter) ] = useState(startingValue);
}
```

However, this is apparently an invalid use of eval().

Expected:
(inputs: "name=audiobooks", startingValue=[]) I want that line to evaluate to `const [audiobooks, setAudiobooks] = useState([]);`
(inputs: name="julyBookClub", startingValue=[]) I want that line to evaluate to `const [julyBookClub, setJulyBookClub] = useState([]);`
(inputs: name="myString", "") I want that line to evaluate to `const [myString, setMyString] = useState("");`

Comment: Why not store an object in a state variable, where the keys are the names of the shelves and the values are the corresponding arrays? This way, you have a single object to which you can add/remove shelves as you need

Comment: I think the rules of hook wont allow dynamic creation, https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#rules-of-hooks
you can create a state which is like a list with a key constaining you data,
see examples of array state updates
https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `useState` is essentially a React hook, and using that inside your `newStateVariable` method would obviously not work, hence there's no such way to 'create' a state variable on runtime.

Your question indicates there might be a better way to go about it - architecturally speaking.

Here's my suggestion - instead of creating a new state for a category (e.g, `julyBook` [which would cause a re-render anyway], why don't you add the category to a `categories` state variable? i.e, something like

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState([
    {
      name: "julyBook",
      // other properties
    },
    {
      name: "someOtherCategoryName",
      // properties
    },
  ]);
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I ended up doing. I was definitely overthinking it initially. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, after doing that how do i update the state for `julyBook` and not `someOtherCategoryName`?

Comment: @kd12345 You will have to do something like const `catIdx =  category.findIndex(cat=>cat.name === 'julyBook')`, and `const catCopy = category.slice()`, `catCopy[catIdx] = {...catCopy[catIdx], //properties to update }`

If the updates are more frequent, you can also keep `category` as an object which maps the name (if that's the unique identifier) against the details, doing that would reduce the number of array searches, resulting in better performance